# jquery ui animation time delay

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-animate

I got a litte function that should create an endless bouncing effect on an icon.

```
function animMap1(){
    $("img.map_icon").animate({ top:"165px" },   300,"easeInOutQuad",function(){animMap2();});
    }
function animMap2(){
    $("img.map_icon").animate({ top:"185px" },300,"easeInOutQuad",function(){animMap1();});
    }
```

It works but each time it's fired a little delay is added. Where is my mistake? What I want to achieve is something like this:

http://www.porte-sainte-claire.com/#page_venir-a-la-porte-sainte-claire

Any ideas? Thanks in advance!!

Comment: Wish you were using [**`TweenMax`**](http://greensock.com/docs/#/HTML5/GSAP/TweenMax/) for all your animation needs. Would've been a matter of a single line:

`TweenMax.fromTo($('img.map_icon'), .3, {top: 165}, {top: 185, ease: Expo.easeOut, repeat: -1, yoyo: true});`.

Comment: This TweenMax stuff is a really good tool. Thanks for the hind!

Comment: You will be surprised :)

Answer (score 1):

```js
function animMap1(){
  $(this).children('.dropingdiv').css("display", "block");
   $("img.map_icon").animate({ top:"165px" },{duration:300, complete: function() {
    $("img.map_icon").animate({ top:"185px" },{duration:300, complete: function() {
      animMap1();
        }});
}});
```